# ScalaTest needed settings with multi-project sbt

Tags: scala, sbt, scalatest

I neither can run test becauses any of them are detected and when compilator complains it's to explain me that i can't import classes from /core/src/main in /core/src/test when i m interactively running sbt in core project.

Here is the basic configuration i'm using.

Folder organization

```
|
| build.sbt
|
|-------------- core | src ------------| main | scala | files...
|                    | build.sbt       | test | scala | files...
|
|-------------- proj1 | src ----------- | main | scala | files...
|                     | build.sbt       | test | scala | files...
```

Here some peace of the build.sbt

```scala
lazy val deps = Seq(
    "org.scalactic" %% "scalactic" % "3.1.2",
    "org.scalatest" %% "scalatest" % "3.1.2" % "test"
)

lazy val coreDeps = libraryDependencies ++= deps


lazy val core = (project in file("core"))
   .settings(coreDeps)

lazy val proj1 = (project in file("proj1"))
  .settings(coreDeps)
  .dependsOn(core)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Problem came from build.sbt files which were under `core` and `proj1` once i remove them, everything works as expected.

Answer (score 0):

You just need to do what it says in the comment: apply the settings using the `settings` method:

```scala
lazy val core = (project in file("core"))
  .settings(
    libraryDependencies ++= Seq(
      "org.scalactic" %% "scalactic" % "3.1.2",
      "org.scalatest" %% "scalatest" % "3.1.2" % "test"
    )
  )

lazy val proj1 = (project in file("proj1"))
  .settings(
    libraryDependencies ++= Seq(
      "org.scalactic" %% "scalactic" % "3.1.2",
      "org.scalatest" %% "scalatest" % "3.1.2" % "test"
    )
  )
```

Alternatively, you can scope the `libraryDependencies` key to `ThisBuild`. Then it will be inherited in all the subprojects:

```scala
ThisBuild / libraryDependencies ++= Seq(
  "org.scalactic" %% "scalactic" % "3.1.2",
  "org.scalatest" %% "scalatest" % "3.1.2" % "test"
)

lazy val core = (project in file("core"))
lazy val proj1 = (project in file("proj1"))
```

Comment: It was the case, i fixed the question, and issue is still running

Comment: Then the problem is not in build.sbt. You need to prepare a minimal, reproducible example. https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example